# My recent changes in NIB file is not displayed in ios simulator-closed

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, ios-simulator

I've applied changes in interface builder for my app which has labels in it. I just changed the name and position of a label and in addition to that I changed the font of a text view in my app. When I started to run my app, the font remains the same as previous one and none of the labels are displayed in it.

Can anyone help it pls?

Comment: Reset the simulator and clean the compiler. Command+Shift+B will clean the compiler while to reset iOS simulator you have to go to the menu bar and find rest under iOS simulator.

Comment: Just clean your project Command+Shift+B and delete app from simulator...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Xcode try this: main menu:product:Clean

if not enough: main menu:Xcode:preferences:  ->  click over locations icon:
click over the little gray right arrow for derived data:

that will show you the finder folder "DerivedData": delete it.

one other thing to try: in simulator, delete your app.

Answer (score 2):

quite your xcode and then again open your project . Clear your build then run your code.

Answer (score 2):

You should also make sure, that the interfacebuilder file is linked to the target you are starting in simulator.
To do this, select your xib and open the File inspector. There you should see a dropdown named "Target Membership" where you can link the xib to the targets you want.

Also be sure to have the labels defined as IBOutlets in your header file and link them correctly in your xib. Easiest way to do this is using the Assistant Editor and drag the outlet to the header file.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem - but only on the iPhone non-retina in the simulator. Cleaning the code did not help. Restarting and rebooting did not help. But removing the app from the simulator worked. Now changes to my UI show up next time I run.
To remove the app from the simulator I did it just like on a real phone. I select the app icon with the mouse and hold it down the mouse button for a few seconds. Then the icon displays a small delete icon that you can select (the app icons shakes too).